# Recyclerview starting animation

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to get an initial animation for my `RecyclerView` that starts with the items stacked on top of each other, and then spread out like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xKHTqtwfKtdlFlU3FEWG9pTFU/view?usp=sharing

I'm already familiar with animations in Android, but have no idea how to do something like this. Any suggestions?

I am using MvvmCross, if that makes a difference.